freecodecamp html step 56 whats wrong with this code?
What's wrong with this code? The virtual tutor says:
Sorry, your code does not pass. Don't give up.
The text Loving should be wrapped in a label element.
<label for="loving"> LOVING </label> 
  <input id="loving" type="checkbox">

The code above is what I tried. I was expecting the tutor to accept the code as "correct."

Machine checking can sometimes be very literal. Like maybe the work Loving should not have spaces around it, or shouldn't be all caps. Try some variations and see what happens.

maybe, you should try lOVING ?

freecodecamp has it's own space for questions like this.. Please clarify why you are asking this here and provide all the relevant details from the course and step, as questions should be self- contained.

Try putting in Loving in the label rather then LOVING.
In the question it says "The text Loving should be wrapped in a label element.", so i would assume that capitalisation will be important

You are saying "what" but not "why". Why would that fix anything? [answer]

No where in that article does it talk about saying why and answer is rather then just what an answer it, but i appreciate that the original poster is doing a course so the why would be useful to them. I was just thinking from my perspective if i had asked the question then someone just putting my original answer would of told my how and why to fix it - as it would of occurred to me that capitalisation is important.  I've now edited my answer to show why.

You don't learn when someone is just given the answer without knowing the why. As the link states, we are here to "learn as a community". You acknowledge this when you replied, "i appreciate that the original poster is doing a course so the why would be useful to them". SO is not a cut-and-paste resource.
